Error with unlink() function of symfony in prod
I have a problem with my app
It is deployed with symfony 6.3.2 on the backend I think it's on an nginx server with docker
The library used for the api is api-platform
Whenever I make some calls to API like BASE_URL/api/currencies
1-2 times out of 10 I have an error
This is part of the trace
{
    {
    "@context": "\/api\/contexts\/Error",
    "@type": "hydra:Error",
    "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
    "hydra:description": "unlink(): Argument #1 ($filename) must not contain any null bytes",
    "trace": [
        {
            "namespace": "",
            "short_class": "",
            "class": "",
            "type": "",
            "function": "",
            "file": "\/app\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/Profiler\/FileProfilerStorage.php",
            "line": 332,
            "args": []
        },
        {
            "namespace": "",
            "short_class": "",
            "class": "",
            "type": "",
            "function": "unlink",
            "file": "\/app\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/Profiler\/FileProfilerStorage.php",
            "line": 332,
            "args": []
        },
        {
            "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Profiler",
            "short_class": "FileProfilerStorage",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Profiler\\FileProfilerStorage",
            "type": "->",
            "function": "removeExpiredProfiles",
            "file": "\/app\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/Profiler\/FileProfilerStorage.php",
            "line": 182,
            "args": []
        }

So the error is from the unlink() function which is used to delete files
From what I read from New in symfony 6.3 (improvements) , they introduced a feature to automatically delete profiles after some time. In practice, on each request there's a 10% random chance that Symfony activates the deletion feature. When it's activated, any profile created two days ago or earlier is deleted.
Which surely explains why sometimes my requests fail and sometimes they work it is surely trying to remove expired profiles with removeExpiredProfiles() function
What is strange is that even when the request fails I get the data at the beginning
This is an example of when it works
{
    "@context": "\/api\/contexts\/Currency",
    "@id": "\/api\/currencies\/1",
    "@type": "Currency",
    "id": 1,
    "uuid": "018ec2aa-3105-71a3-bc59-bd5e81b146ef",
    "code": "EUR",
    "name": "Euros"
}

And this is an example of when it fails
{
    "@context": "\/api\/contexts\/Currency",
    "@id": "\/api\/currencies\/1",
    "@type": "Currency",
    "id": 1,
    "uuid": "018ec2aa-3105-71a3-bc59-bd5e81b146ef",
    "code": "EUR",
    "name": "Euros"
}{
    "@context": "\/api\/contexts\/Error",
    "@type": "hydra:Error",
    "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
    "hydra:description": "unlink(): Argument #1 ($filename) must not contain any null bytes",
    "trace": [
        {
            "namespace": "",
            "short_class": "",
            "class": "",
            "type": "",
            "function": "",
            "file": "\/app\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/Profiler\/FileProfilerStorage.php",
            "line": 332,
            "args": []
        },
        {
            "namespace": "",
            "short_class": "",
            "class": "",
            "type": "",
            "function": "unlink",
            "file": "\/app\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/Profiler\/FileProfilerStorage.php",
            "line": 332,
            "args": []
        },
        {
            "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Profiler",
            "short_class": "FileProfilerStorage",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Profiler\\FileProfilerStorage",
            "type": "->",
            "function": "removeExpiredProfiles",
            "file": "\/app\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/Profiler\/FileProfilerStorage.php",
            "line": 182,
            "args": []
        },
                ...

Any help would greatly be appreciated
Thanks
What I tried to do is to clone the backend locally in dev mode with the exact versions of php, symfony, and all packages installed by composer as the ones in prod
I exepcted to have the same error in dev and conclude that some libraries were not up to date
But in dev I never have that error
I don't understand why

The error indicates that the issue lies with the profiler. In production, it should normally be disabled.
Which composer command did you use in production to install your packages?
What is the value of your APP_ENV in your .env file?

I don't have access to the actual prod config I will ask my boss
On gitlab it's APP_ENV=dev
But when the profiler is active we see a bar on the bottom of the page right?? I don't have it in prod so I think it's disabled

To install the packages I used composer install

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

It is necessary to ensure that in production the variable APP_ENV is set to prod on the production servers.
On production, you need to execute: composer install –no-dev
Adding “–no-dev” excludes the packages required for the development environment (including the profiler).
Therefore, it is possible that you have installed the development-related packages with APP_ENV=prod and hence you might have a conflict at this level.
Try removing the packages on the server and re-running a composer install –no-dev

APP_ENV was actually set to dev
Thanks
Setting it to prod solved the issue
